# How can i wrap a text via css

Tags: css, word-wrap

i am trying to wrap a long text inside a table but facing the problem that the long text overlaps other content.

Example:

```css
table td {
  white-space: nowrap;
  max-width: 10em;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
}

table td:hover {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Headline 1</th>
            <th>Headline 2</th>
            <th>Headline 3</th>
        </tr>  
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Bet at home</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>80%</td>
        </tr> 
        <tr>
            <td>MOSER 2384 Schermaschine Moser</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>40%</td>
        </tr> 
        <tr>
            <td>Bg24 Single 600x120</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>50%</td>
        </tr> 
    </tbody>    
</table
```

Is there a way to avoid this maybe by adding a non transparent background to the content? How can i handle this problem?

Regards,
Kai

Comment: @Nit hover the second item.

Comment: Why not just get rid of the line where you TELL it not to wrap?:   `white-space: nowrap;`

Comment: Jumpy but have you tried to add `white-space` `normal` or `pre-wrap;`

Answer (score 1):

Just add `whitespace:normal` in your hover.

```css
table td {
  white-space: nowrap;
  max-width: 10em;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
}

table td:hover {
    overflow: visible;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Headline 1</th>
            <th>Headline 2</th>
            <th>Headline 3</th>
        </tr>  
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Bet at home</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>80%</td>
        </tr> 
        <tr>
            <td>MOSER 2384 Schermaschine Moser</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>40%</td>
        </tr> 
        <tr>
            <td>Bg24 Single 600x120</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>50%</td>
        </tr> 
    </tbody>    
</table
```

Comment: Could be a solution but it would be nice to avoid a new line on hover.

Comment: It would be nice if there is no new line when hovering and the long text also should not overlap the other content. So when the long text is shown on hover it should be readable.

Comment: no new line and do not overlap the other columns. It means your column size should change that would not be very good. Instead use a tool tip. Design the tool tip so that it differs from the one you are already using.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do *anything* on hover (i.e. remove `table td:hover`). Because when you set `overflow` to `hidden`, by default a tooltip is already displayed when you hover, which shows you the full text - it is significally easier to read than if you expand and move the table rows by expanding some of them.

> [image]

```css
table td {
  white-space: nowrap;
  max-width: 10em;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Headline 1</th>
            <th>Headline 2</th>
            <th>Headline 3</th>
        </tr>  
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Bet at home</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>80%</td>
        </tr> 
        <tr>
            <td>MOSER 2384 Schermaschine Moser</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>40%</td>
        </tr> 
        <tr>
            <td>Bg24 Single 600x120</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>50%</td>
        </tr> 
    </tbody>    
</table
```

Comment: The tooltip/title-attribute is already used by other informations, so cant be used for the long text.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
whitespace: normal;
```

or try

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
```

in your hover.

Answer (score 0):

What about using word-break attibute to  element?

```
table td{      
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I-m not sure if that is what are you looking for , but I couldn't find another solution

```
table td:hover {
    overflow: visible;
    max-width:100%;
}
```

[fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/coy3qtpb/5/)